Azure Monitor metrics rest API multiple aggregation values
I tried to use the Azure Monitor REST API to read the Azure Service Bus metrics.
According to Microsoft example Get Metrics data, the parameter aggregation is potential list of average,minimum,maximum
However, the response has only value of average.
How can I retrieve values of average, minimum and maximum in a single request?
Expected response as mentioned:
"data": [
            {
              "timeStamp": "2021-04-20T09:00:00Z",
              "average": 7,
              "minimum": 7,
              "maximum": 7
            }
         ]



How can I retrieve values of average, minimum and maximum in a single request?

To retrieve values of all the three in a single request, you can simply use a comma(,) separator and pass it as aggregation=average,minimum,maximum as shown below with the whole URL.
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/newsbj/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?timespan=2024-06-07T07:30:31Z/2024-06-07T08:30:31Z&interval=PT6H&metricnames=IncomingRequests&aggregation=minimum,maximum,average&api-version=2023-10-01

Output:



I tried the same and I realize that it works with IncomingRequests but it does not work with ActiveMessages. Have you tried with this metrics?

Is it so! Let me check with ActiveMessages also. @MinhTrần

I am able to retrieve ActiveMessages metric also as shown here. @MinhTrần

Check the timestamp you are using and pass it accurately. @MinhTrần

Thank @Jahnavi, I remove the parameter $filter=EntityName eq '*' and then I can return all the aggregations. However, it means that I can not see the metrics for each topic/queue.

With the parameter $filter, the returned metrics is grouping for each topic/queue. In fact, I need to monitor the ActiveMessages for each one.

My screenshot is here

Ok now you are able to retrieve it but not for each individual entity? Is that the issue! @MinhTrần

For me, I think it's inconvenient. Because I need to make 3 API calls to query enough metrics for a specific entity. Each call for one aggregation maximum, minimum or average

Have you tried using the comma operator as shown in the above answer. @MinhTrần

Yes I did, as mentioned in my screenshot

Though you have passed it, it was showing only aggregation? @MinhTrần

Can you provide the REST uri using in your environment once. I will try in mine. @MinhTrần

It is https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/:subscription_id/resourceGroups/:resource_group/providers/:resource_provider_namespace/:resource_type/:resource_name/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version={{azure_monitor_api_version}}&metricnamespace=Microsoft.ServiceBus/Namespaces&metricnames=ActiveMessages&timespan=2024-06-06T00:00:00Z/2024-06-06T01:00:00Z&resultType=data&$filter=EntityName eq '*'&interval=PT5M&aggregation=minimum,maximum,average&top=3&orderby=average desc

I think there is any other constraints around this, because for the same API and parameters, it works for IncomingRequests but ActiveMessages
